# Express-Validator fail on unknown key

Tags: node.js, express

I am working with nodejs, express, and express-validator to create a type safe rest api.
What I want is that when the user passes in a request that contains one or many extra keys that the validation fails.

These are my validator rules:

```
const prepaidValidationRules = () => {
    return [
        body('accountHolder').exists().isString(),
        body('amount').exists().isFloat()
    ]
}
```

Now when some sends the following request body:

```
{
        "amount": 20.0,
        "accountHolder": "Claude"
}
```

Then the validation succeedes as expected, but when I send the following request body:

```
{
        "amount": 20.0,
        "accountHolder": "Claude",
        "extrakey": "someValue"
}
```

Then I want the validation to fail.
Is there anyway to do this using express-validaiton.

Thank you very much for any help :)

Comment: I think the best way to to this is using a json shema. You can use declaration instead of imperative code to specify the body. You can get a full descriptive message of the error using libraries, that you can send back to the client easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave this here if someone wants to achieve the same.
I simply used currying to achieve what I wanted:

```
app.post("/someRoute", validationRule(), validate(2), doSomething());
```

validate function

```
function validate(nmbOfExpectedKeys) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (Object.keys(req.requestBody) > nmbOfExpectedKeys)
            return res.status(422);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail if you replace some field by another name. For example your validation rules only allows `name` field, and you pass as body a `surname` field the validation will pass.

Answer (score 3):

This one works to me

```
const { body } = require("express-validator");
...
...
body().custom((body) => {
  const allowedKeys = [
    "name",
    "age",
    "bio",
  ];
  for (const key of Object.keys(body)) {
    if (!allowedKeys.includes(key)) {
      throw new Error(`Unknown property: ${key}`);
    }
  }
  return true;
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disallow unknow fields with express-validator, but you need to do an extra function.

**The middleware function:***

```js
import { validationResult } from 'express-validator'

export function validate (validators, allowExtraFields = false) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    // You can meka the validation optional
    if (!allowExtraFields) {
      // Fields validation
      const extraFields = checkIfExtraFields(validators, req)
      if (extraFields) { res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'Bad request' }) }
    }
    // Type validation
    await Promise.all(validators.map((validator) => validator.run(req)))
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next()
    }
    logger.error(`${req.ip} try to make a invalid request`)
    return res.status(400).json({ error: true, errors: errors.array() })
  }
}


function checkIfExtraFields (validators, req) {
  const allowedFields = validators.reduce((fields, rule) => {
    return [...fields, ...rule.builder.fields]
  }, []).sort()

  // Check for all common request inputs
  const requestInput = { ...req.query, ...req.params, ...req.body }
  const requestFields = Object.keys(requestInput).sort()

  if (JSON.stringify(allowedFields) === JSON.stringify(requestFields)) {
    return false
  }
  logger.error(`${req.ip} try to make a invalid request`)
  return true
}
```

**Usage**

```js
import { body, query } from 'express-validator'

const validator = [
  body('email').isEmail().exist(),
  query('new').isString(),
]

router.post(
  '/user',
  validate(validator ), // By default all extrange fields are rejected
  handler.post
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Good approach. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the [v7.0.0](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/releases/tag/v7.0.0) express validator release you can use **checkExact** middleware. [See docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/api/check-exact/)

Example:

```
app.post(
  '/signup',
  // All of name, email and password are known fields in req.body. Everything else is unknown.
  checkExact([
        body('name').notEmpty(),
        body('email').isEmail(), 
        body('password').isLength({ min: 8 })], 
  {
    message: 'Too many fields specified',
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Handle request
  },
);
```